# Is it possible to create an on-the-fly (soft) dblink in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, dblink

Wondering if it is possible to create a dblink in postgresql that is not saved as an object in the db, but rather it is an in-memory object during the session of a function or running code? Then use it to connect and do queries.

New to postgresql and not sure how to search for this.

Any examples on how to do this?

Comment: [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html) is an extension, not an "object" that you need to create in the db. Once the extension is installed, dblink is a function that is called, not an object that is created.

Comment: Unfortunate. Any way to make an on-the-fly connection to another db by some other way? I believe MSSQL has this ability.

Comment: Yes, dblink can make connections on the fly